# Javascript React Return Spread Operator Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have the graphQL query with the following schema:

```js
export const ALL_BOOKS = gql`
  query {
    allBooks {
      title
      published
      author {
        name
        born
      }
      id
      genres
    }
  }
```

I have passed this result to a react component through props. I am trying to get the genres of each book and store it in an array of a single dimension. To me, it makes perfect sense to write:

```
let genres = props.books.map(book => (...book.genres))
```

Why does this code not work? What is wrong with returning an object with the spread operator and what alternative do you think would work to return books>book>genres>genre into a single array. I really want to avoid the nested-for-loop thing.

Thanks!

Input structure is like so:

```
0: {__typename: 'Book', title: 'Book1', published: 2022, author: 
{…}, id: '61d5e02beef9d5fcdb5ce26b', …}
1: {__typename: 'Book', title: 'Book2', published: 2022, author: 
{…}, id: '61d5e061eef9d5fcdb5ce270', …}
2: {__typename: 'Book', title: 'Book3', published: 2022, author: 
{…}, id: '61d5e07a3473e9ac212f87dc', …}
```

Taken from console log

--
With Stringfy

```
[
{
  "__typename": "Book",
  "title": "The Key of Solomon",
  "published": 2022,
  "author": {
    "__typename": "Author",
    "name": "Steve Jobs",
    "born": 1999
  },
  "id": "61d5e02beef9d5fcdb5ce26b",
  "genres": [
    "Philosophy",
    "Witchcraft"
  ]
},
{
  "__typename": "Book",
  "title": "The Steez of Solomon",
  "published": 2022,
  "author": {
    "__typename": "Author",
    "name": "Horace Gumdrop",
    "born": 1998
  },
  "id": "61d5e061eef9d5fcdb5ce270",
  "genres": [
    "Philosophy",
    "Steezcraft"
  ]
  },
{
  "__typename": "Book",
  "title": "The Steep",
  "published": 2022,
  "author": {
    "__typename": "Author",
    "name": "Bulhar",
    "born": null
  },
  "id": "61d5e07a3473e9ac212f87dc",
  "genres": [
    "Philosophy",
    "Steezcraft"
  ]
}
```

]

Comment: What is `...book.genres` supposed to be spreading it _into_? Did you just want `props.books.map(({ genres }) => genres)` (destructuring genres _out_ of the book, rather than trying to put it into something)?

Comment: You're not returning an object, that would be `book => ({ ...book.genres })`.

Comment: And can you post example input instead? (also note that graphQL and React are completely irrelevant, this question is only about extracting array B from array A)

Comment: Share most segments of your code to better understanding of your purpose

Comment: need to return genres of every single book in array of dimension 1: [genre1Book1, genre2Book1,genre1Book2,...etc]

Comment: Please use `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` and shorten it so we can see the structure properly, *including the relevant **genre** part* -- Also, you can probably use `map(book => book.genres)` then `.flatten()` the result

Comment: Shared - still no answer

Comment: Check the updated answer, it should work as expected

Comment: I'd push the genres into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), then turn it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let genres = props.books.map(book => ({...book.genres}))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that you only want to return the genres:

```
let genres = props.books.map(book => book.genres)
```

This will return an array with the genres extracted from the `books` prop

Later edit: your question was unclear, but probably you want to get the entire list of genres from each genres sublist AND remove duplicates:

```
let genres = props.books.map(book => book.genres).flat().reduce((arr, elem) => {
    if(arr.indexOf(elem) === -1) {
       arr.push(elem);
    }  

    return arr;

}, []);
```

Comment: question was clear about 1 dimensional return

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to add `.flat()` after the `.map(...)`.

Or you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to accumulate the result.